# Live and dead loads on lift core (passenger and cargo)

Tags: concrete

According to Eurocode or even better - JUS standards (if there is someone from EX-JU countries here), what are the dead and live load values and schemes for reinforced concrete lift core for both cases: passenger lift and cargo lift?

How do you design and model the rc core?

Answer (score 0):

The lift core is considered and designed as the shear wall according to the code. Depending on its relationship to the surrounding structures, the dead load and live loads (including lateral load) vary. The linked article provides a quick peek into the design of a shear wall.

https://www.structuralguide.com/shear-walls/

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is helpful.

What about the loads? I'm aware that loads sometimes vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, but however for most cases there are general directions with minimal loads. Do you have some information about that?

Comment: Are you talking about the lift/elevator rather than the concrete shaft? It will vary very much from manufacturer to manufacturer, also the model, the capacity... You shall contact the lift suppliers to get the information you need for the design. Why not try searching the famous manufacture's websites such as GE, Hitachi...

Comment: I'm talking about the reinforced concrete core in which the lift will be "stored" so to speak. For sure there will be interaction between them - transfer of loads. Some of them will go on the rc foundation slab, but others on the walls.

I've searched few local manufacturers, but they don't provide enough information about the loads. I have some guidance for passenger lifts, but still. Most of my colleagues as far as I know, don't bother to much with this, but I would like to do it as much thoroughly as I can.

Comment: Compare to the weight of the concrete walls, the weight of the lift is negligibly small, as well as its inertia force during an earthquake. I believe, prior to the final design, the effect of lift is largely ignored. And its effects might not even back checked except for its fastening mechanisms which are localized concerns. Do not forget the large safety factors embedded in the design code. So relax.

Comment: Yes, compared to the horizontal/inertia force during an earthquake, probably is small and can be ignored. However I'll add live loads on the foundation/footing slab and the last slab (according to the load guide that I've found). If I find a better approach I'll let you know.

Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Wish you luck. You might never get the info until the manufacture affirms you have the potential/intention as a customer.

Comment: So far, no one from the manufactureres have answered my emails. :) 
But i'll find my way, i'm persistent. xD

Comment: You can estimate the weight by yourself. The usual size of the elevator is about 14'x14'x9.5' that can hold 10-15 persons. Use that dimension to estimate the shell weight, then double it to allow for counterweight. The total should come about a few percentages around the real weight.

Comment: I did something similar and I calculated it like shear wall - with hidden "columns" (bars and stirrups) at the corners, plus regular mesh on both zones. According to the loads, of course. And it seems logical.